# Assembly local variables and register

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I have this C code that is disassembled (AT&T) and I have some confusion with two things. The first, my understanding is that EBP-4 should be the first local variable (here, int i) on the stack. I is clearly in EBP-8 here. Why is this?

Second, is it necessary to move values into registers before performing arithmetic operations on them? (this is an x86 32 bit machine) example:

`0x08048402 <+21>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax        //move parameter a into eax
 0x08048405 <+24>:    add    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)        //r += a`

Why cant this be :

`0x08048405 <+24>:    add     0x8(%ebp),-0x4(%ebp)        //r += a`

C code:

```
int loop_w (int a, int b){     
    int i = 0;     
    int r = a;    
    while ( i < 256){         
      r += a;         
      a -= b;         
      i += b;
    }  
return r;
```

Disassembly:

```
Dump of assembler code for function loop_w:
   0x080483ed <+0>:     push   %ebp
   0x080483ee <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080483f0 <+3>:     sub    $0x10,%esp
---------------Above is for stack setup-----------------
   0x080483f3 <+6>:     movl   $0x0,-0x8(%ebp)         //I=0
   0x080483fa <+13>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax          //move parameter a into eax
   0x080483fd <+16>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)        //move a into local var  (r=a)
   0x08048400 <+19>:    jmp    0x8048414 <loop_w+39>    //start while loop
   0x08048402 <+21>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax        //move parameter a into eax
   0x08048405 <+24>:    add    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)        //r += a
   0x08048408 <+27>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax        //move parameter b into eax
   0x0804840b <+30>:    sub    %eax,0x8(%ebp)        //a += parameter b
   0x0804840e <+33>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax        //move parameter b into eax
   0x08048411 <+36>:    add    %eax,-0x8(%ebp)        //i+=b
   0x08048414 <+39>:    cmpl   $0xff,-0x8(%ebp)         //compare i to 256
   0x0804841b <+46>:    jle    0x8048402 <loop_w+21>    //continue loop if failed condition
=> 0x0804841d <+48>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax        //move r into eax
   0x08048420 <+51>:    leave
   0x08048421 <+52>:    ret                //return eax
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: It all depends upon whether the compiler allocates variables from the start of the stack upon entry or after allocating from the stack (the latter is more common). Notice that in order of ascending memory, i is located before r (as is normal).

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can decide wherever it wants to place the local variable. It might have placed it at %ebp - 8 for alignment reasons.

For your second question - Do variables have to be loaded into registers before operation, depends on the operation and the instruction set provided by the architecture.

You mentioned x86. So particular to this architecture, X86 doesn't allow instructions with two memory operands (yes there are a few exceptions).

You can search per instruction basis to know what kind of operands they allow.

Comment: Thank you. I'm currently studying this - so if I were writing assembly code into C code (on paper), it wouldn't be wrong to say %ebp-4 is "i" then?

Comment: Yes it would be wrong to make the assumption that %ebp - 4 is i. You might be tempted to look at the generated assembly and determine the offset for each variable on the stack, but that is not a scalable nor a portable way. Instead you can look at gcc and clang supported extended inline assembly. They allow you to write the variable names instead of offsets and the compiler will place the appropriate adress (or register) for you.

Comment: @KenP I say not portable because even same compiler with different optimization flags can place locals at different offsets. In some cases, compiler might not even place the variable on the stack and just keep it as a register (for faster access ofcourse).

Comment: But yes if you are writing your own assembly on paper you can do any stack allocation. You can place i at %ebp - 4. In that case you are a compiler in your self :)

Comment: Sorry I read your question wrong before. I thought you were talking about writing assembly inline with C code. To answer your question, yes you can place i at -4(%ebp) as long as you follow the same for every reference of i in the function.